# How can I alert an asynchronous function that another instance of the same function has fired?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I am wanting to create an alert inside my function which tracks if any other instances of the same function have fired during a 15 second period. this is what I have so far:

```
 bar = 0;

 async function Counting() {
   bar += 1;
   foo = bar;
   new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
   if (bar == foo) {
     //Do something
   }
   else {
     return;
   }
 }
```

I'm using bar as a global counter and foo as a function instance counter, but for some reason all instances of the function update at the same time.

How can I check if this function has fired during the 15 second waiting period and then stop all previous instances of the function if this is the case?

Comment: Can you show some real code that shows a real problem.  That code you show executes `Counting()` synchronously and immediately returns.   There will be a promise still waiting to resolve for 5 seconds, but your function doesn't wait for it so there's nothing still running there. So, there's no previous instances actually doing anything in your example.  Stopping asynchronous operations that are in-flight has no generic answer - it depends entirely upon the specific asynchronous operation.  So, I don't think we can help you with the generic question you've asked.

Comment: To help you, we will need to see real code with real asynchronous operations and then you explain a real problem with that code that you need to solve.

Comment: @jfriend00, You are very correct that this is not specific at all. I have already asked this question two other times and was too detailed for anyone to help, so I decided to take an alternate approach and make a general case for what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @jfriend00, Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Your `foo` variable is not local to the function call, you probably want to use `var`/`let`/`const`. And you are not `await`ing that promise!

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks, I for sure will now use let and const, I managed to get my code working by doing so! But what do you mean when you say I'm not using await? Where should I add it and why would it help?

Comment: @Nickfriesen You create a promise that will fulfill after 5s, but you never do anything with that promise. If you want your `Counting` function to wait, then you have to use `await`.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for the tip! I have added this to my personal code and it is working well!

Answer (score 0):

Earlier today I asked a question similar to this and someone by the username of @FedericoMoretti was able to help me out. He suggested using let and const variables which did the trick in my specific case.

```
 let bar = 0;

 async function Counting() {
   bar += 1;
   const foo = bar;
   new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
   if (bar == foo) {
     //Do something
   }
   else {
     return;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your solution is a bit overly complicated. I think what you're describing is function debouncing:

> It can be a little harder to explain. With debouncing, it’s like “Hey, I’m not going to execute that function until I know there are no more changes inbound”. We don’t execute our function until everyone else is happy and we’re clear to proceed. Imagine ordering food at a restaurant. You start listing off items to the waiter/waitress and at the end they ask “Is that everything?” If it is, they leave you to it and go get your food and drinks. If it isn’t, you add to the order and then they ask you again until they are clear to proceed.
>   - Throttling and Debouncing in JavaScript - Jhey Tompkins
>   - https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Basically something like this:

```js
const fn = (() => {
  let timer = null;
  const myFn = () => {
    timer = null;
    console.log('My fn has been ran!');
  };
  return () => {
    if(timer != null){
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(myFn,5000);
  };
})();
```

This way when you call your function, it will wait 15 seconds to run the actual logic. However, if the function is called again within that 15 seconds, the timer restarts.

Usually for something like this you use a library function to do it so you don't have to write all this boilerplate each time:

```js
function debounce(fn,time){
  let timer = null;
  return function(...args){
    if(timer != null){
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(fn.bind(this,...args),5000);
  };
}

// Usage
const myFn = debounce((name) => {
  console.log('Hello %s!',name);
},1000);

// This function won't output "Hello !"
myFn('Joe');
// This function will
myFn('John');
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help! I like the idea, but I'm confused as to why my answer is more complicated. My answer takes 4 steps, which seems to be less steps than your answer. If there is an issue I would run into down the road while using my answer, than please tell me; otherwise, I may stick to the solution I have currently of using let and const for my two variables.

Comment: @Nickfriesen Maybe it's just me, but it's not totally clear that your code is debouncing. All I see is a variable increasing and a check on the variable. Usually when you see a debounce you clear a timeout and create a new timeout. Though, I agree, after understanding your code a bit better, it is less code.

Comment: The if statement is the debounce check. The is statement checks if the function is the most recently run function of its kind and then continues if it is, and returns if not.